# Change select2 style using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I try to change select2 box style using jQuery but its not working.

I tried like this

```
jQuery(".select2-container").find(".select2-choice").css("background-image","transparent !important");
```

If I try to change style via css its working fine. I don't know how to change via jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8k2aerf/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/z8k2aerf/3/

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/z8k2aerf/3/)

```
jQuery.when(jQuery("select").select2()).done(function(){
    jQuery(".select2-container").find(".select2-choice").css("background-image","none");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `!important` statement, that should affect the style of the select2-choice.

Comment: @Dineshkani but you should remove the !important, not add

Comment: @Dineshkani also the `background-image` cannot be `transparent`, try to change this to `background`

Comment: I forget to mention "!important" will not work when styles added using jquery